# How to make my extension support opcache in php?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

My extension does not work when enabled opcache extension.
It is normal when i first run my extension(a web page).
But after that,no matter how many times i try,the web page performs very slowly until the timeout(default 30s),Just like in an infinite loop.
I can't provide more information,But debug my script by gdb.
it shows that exited normally.
I need help. Thanks!
more infomation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
```

Comment: There is not much we can do with that little amount of information

Comment: @RiggsFolly more infomation :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/345873/gdb-crashes-with-importerror-no-module-named-libstdcxx-v6-printers